# How do I just get specific fields when displaying transactions for a given account?

Tags: javascript-sdk

I'm using the Javascript SDK. My objective is to get the last 10 transactions for a given account (which is working), but **just** show specific fields (such as the amount of lumens, and perhaps the memo), on each row in the console (which I eventually want to show on an HTML page, but for now  console output is ok while I get over this hurdle).

I have this function (based on one of the stellar.org examples):

```
function ShowTransactions(fromAccount) {
    // Shows a simple list of transactions for the given account
    server.transactions()
    .forAccount(fromAccount)
    .limit(10)
    .order('desc')
    .call()
    .then(function (page) {
        console.log('Page 1: ');
        console.log(page.records);
        return page.next();
    })
    .then(function (page) {
        console.log('Page 2: ');
        console.log(page.records);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

This outputs everything to the console, but I'm not sure how to just specify the specific fields I want to display. Is this something that is done by doing some properties of

```
console.log(page.records. ..(etc)
```

or do I need to do something different ?

Many thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

page.records is an array, you can loop through it like this:

```
page.records.forEach( function(record) {
    console.log("txId: " + record.id);
    console.log("created: " + record.created_at);
    // console.log( record.whatever)
});
```